# Child component's is recall a once problem

Tags: reactjs

The useState's value will change when the current button is clicked, which will call the child component.

Child component is Modal.

However, when the parent's button is repressed, the changed value is not changed again and will not be recalled.

https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-snowflake-wdm78

Comment: `visible` is set as false once you close the modal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send the callback function to the Child Component like this.

> StepComp.js
>
> ```
> const StepComp = () => {
>       const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
>       const btnStyled = {
>         margin: "10rem"
>       };
>     
>       const setVisible = visible => {
>         setIsModalVisible(visible);
>       };
>     
>       return (
>         <div>
>           <Button onClick={() => setIsModalVisible(true)} style={btnStyled}>
>             jump
>           </Button>
>           <LoginModal open={isModalVisible} setVisible={setVisible} />
>         </div>
>       );
>     };
> ```
>
> LoginModal.js
>
> ```
> const LoginModal = ({ open, setVisible }) => {
>   const inputStyled = {
>     borderColor: "none",
>     borderBottom: "1px solid #EBEBEB",
>     marginBottom: "1rem"
>   };
>   return (
>     <div>
>       <Modal
>         title="login"
>         centered
>         visible={open}
>         onOk={() => setVisible(false)}
>         onCancel={() => setVisible(false)}
>       >
>         <div>
>           <input type="text" style={inputStyled} /> <br />
>           <input type="text" style={inputStyled} />
>         </div>
>       </Modal>
>     </div>
>   );
> };
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `isModelVisible` and `visible` state properties, and initializing them a a boolean, then setting them to the opposite. This works, but only the **first** time.

What you need to do is `setVisible(!visible)` and `setIsModalVisible(!isModalVisible)` respectively.

While this will make it work, what I suggest doing instead is actually only having one state property, in the parent (StepComp), which then is passed as a callback to the child (Modal) along with the property whether it is open, then you render the child, if it's true, and use the same setState function in the child to close it.

This approach keeps all the logic for opening the Modal in one component.